# Working with the OptionSerializer

Tags: rust

I'm using the `solana-transaction-status` crate and want to inspect the inner instructions of a given transaction in rust.

I can fetch the transaction data using the RPC and I get a `EncodedConfirmedTransactionWithStatusMeta` object. I try to access the inner instructions using:

```
let inner_instructions = encoded_tx
                                .transaction
                                .meta
                                .to_owned()
                                .unwrap()
                                .inner_instructions;
```

This gives me an object of type `OptionSerializer<Vec<UiInnerInstructions>>`. The issue is that I have no idea how to access and traverse the inner `Vec<UiInnerInstructions>`. The API reference for the type doesn't seem to have an answer either: https://docs.rs/solana-transaction-status/1.14.7/solana_transaction_status/option_serializer/enum.OptionSerializer.html#method.skip

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close!  `OptionSerializer` implements `From` on `Option`: https://docs.rs/solana-transaction-status/1.14.7/solana_transaction_status/option_serializer/enum.OptionSerializer.html#impl-From%3COptionSerializer%3CT%3E%3E-for-Option%3CT%3E

So you can do something like:

```
let inner_instructions: Option<Vec<UiInnerInstructions>> = encoded_tx
                                .transaction
                                .meta
                                .to_owned()
                                .unwrap()
                                .inner_instructions
                                .into();
```